# Yii2: Kartik\editable\Editable close popover on blur or if clicked outside

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v

Using the EditableColumn widget along with text box popup and click on field and popup open. when I click outside any area of the page, the popup does not close

```
  return kartik\editable\Editable::widget ( [
            'name' => 'name' ,
            'size' => 'sm' ,
            'placement' => 'right' ,
            'containerOptions' => [] ,
            'contentOptions' => [] ,
            'inputType' => kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT ,
            'value' => 1 ,
            'editableValueOptions' => [] ,
            'pluginEvents' => [
                "editableSuccess" => "function(event, val, form, data) {
    $.pjax.reload({container: '#name'});
    }" ,
            ] ,
            'formOptions' => [
                'method' => 'post' ,
                'id' => 'form_name' ,
                'action' => [ url ]
            ] ,
            'options' => [
                'id' => 'form_name' ,
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'autoclose' => true
                ] ,
                'maxlength' => '10' ,
            ] ,
            'submitButton' => [
                'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' ,
                'icon' => '' ,
            ] ,
        ] );
```

Comment: It doesn't provide default functionality, But you can do that with JS, Please try the answer below

Comment: @SudharshanNair that is incorrect, it does provide the default functionality for this and you can use `closeOnBlur` as `true` which defaults to `false`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam. You are correct. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the option `'closeOnBlur'=>true,` for the Editable as it defaults to `false`, and remains sticky when clicked outside anywhere.

Also, you are specifying the `pluginOptions` inside the `options` which will add them as an attribute to the input. and you are specifying the URL like `[url]`, do update it to the actual URL when you use the code change your editable code to the following.

```
echo kartik\editable\Editable::widget ( [
    'name' => 'name' ,
    'size' => 'sm' ,
    'placement' => 'right' ,
    'containerOptions' => [] ,
    'contentOptions' => [] ,
    'inputType' => kartik\editable\Editable::INPUT_TEXT ,
    'value' => 1 ,
    'editableValueOptions' => [] ,
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "editableSuccess" => "function(event, val, form, data) {
    $.pjax.reload({container: '#name'});
    }" ,
    ] ,
    'formOptions' => [
        'method' => 'post' ,
        'id' => 'form_name' ,
        'action' => ''
    ] ,
    'closeOnBlur'=>true,
    'options' => [
        'id' => 'form_name' ,
        'maxlength' => '10' ,
    ] ,
    'submitButton' => [
        'class' => 'btn btn-sm btn-primary' ,
        'icon' => '' ,
    ] ,
] );
```